# How to obtain a small tflite file

Tags: tensorflow, microcontroller, tensorflow-lite, esp32

I am tryint to obtain the smallest possible tflite file from a Tensorflow object detection model to be used in a microcontroller (ESP32 with 4MB of flash) ([guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/microcontrollers/get_started)). What I am doing Is just following this [guide](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-train-an-object-detection-model-with-keras/) in order to train a model to detect only one class (a specific object in a image).

I have trained a lot of models (on a host computer), but the final outputs (.cc files obtained by the tflite files) are too big (>4MB, when compiled by xtensa) in order to be deployed in the microcontroller (max 4MB of flash).

I have also done a test using the [ssd_mobilenet_v3_small_coco](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v3_small_coco_2019_08_14.tar.gz) configuration and it creates 1MB of tflite, which is really good and I am able to deploy it on the ESP32, but I cannot use v3 because Tensorflow Lite for C++ doesn't have the MUL operation, from the logs of the ESP32:

> Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'MUL' version '1'

So, if I have understood well, I think that I am stuck to use only the v2 mobilenets because there is a limited subset of operations which can be used so far with Tensorflow lite ([from here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/kernels/all_ops_resolver.cc)).

The steps that I am following to train, convert and deploy the models are:

TRAIN:

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ 
  --pipeline_config_path=training/my_extractor.config
```

CONVERT TO TFLITE:

```
python export_tflite_ssd_graph.py 
  --pipeline_config_path="training/pipeline.config" 
  --trained_checkpoint_prefix="training/model.ckpt-xxx" 
  --output_directory="tflite_output" 
  --add_postprocessing_op=true
```

Then

```
tflite_convert --graph_def_file=tflite_output/tflite_graph.pb
  --output_file=tflite_output/detect.tflite --output_format=TFLITE 
  --input_shapes=1,300,300,3 
  --input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor 
  --output_arrays=TFLite_Detection_PostProcess,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3  
  --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 
  --mean_values=128 --std_dev_values=127 
  --change_concat_input_ranges=false 
  --allow_custom_ops --default_ranges_min=0 
  --default_ranges_max=6 --quantize_weights
```

FINALLY (to have access to the model from C++):

```
xxd -i model.tflite > model_data.cc
```

The final questions are:

1. How can I have an object detection model with the minimum size using a mobilenet v2 (if strictly required to be stuck on the v2)?
2. If I am stuck to use the v3 mobilenet, how can I implement the MUL operation?
3. Am I missing something in the process?

Really appreciate if you can give me advices on that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have resolved your problem. But from [the latest tensorflow lite source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/kernels/all_ops_resolver.cc#L65), seems `MUL` support has been added.

Comment: Hi, I have partially solved the problem as explained [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33797) I am still missing the HARD_SWISH operation. The solution so far should just be to wait the developers to add this missing operation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PR about to be merged in master for hard swish support.So you can try using the ssd mobilevet v3 in mcu once it is merged as all the ops in it would be supported.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/37641